# apply zoom event with array of images of image view in UIScrllView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, xcode4, ipod-touch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

int numberOfImages = 32;
CGFloat currentX = 0.0f;

for (int i=1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {

    // create image
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // put image on correct position
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.origin.x = currentX;
    imageView.frame = rect;

    // update currentX
    currentX +=454; //mageView.frame.size.width;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, 800);
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 15;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
}
```

in above code when i apply zoom or tap event with a single image then it work for that. But when same event apply for array of image then not working. why is it happened?

Comment: in above code i have not written code for zoom function. because i have try but it not working. so u tell what code i write and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quiet complex to implement zoom in this kind of image flow. Anyway i wil suggest you one idea,

Add the gesture to each imageView. In the method, add a new scrollview, with the respective imageView.. then implement zoom.

**EDIT:**

In the tapgesture method,

1.Find out the which imageView is visible at that time.

2.Then create a new scrollview,with that single imageview.

3.Implement zoom functionality in that new scrollview.

4.During zoom out,If the new scrollview size is equal to the actual value,remove the new scrollview fro the super view so that the array of images is visible.

Comment: i have add gesture with scroll view ahich is add to image view.

Comment: now at persent win iphone simulator when i tap on any image then in console it show coordinates of points. so that now what i write code in that event so it zoom image?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is create `a big wrapper view` first, and insert it into ScrollView.
And then add all your imageViews to the `wrapper view`.

Comment: how i create wrapper view? i don't have any idea about that. can u tall me in brief?